# Run React-Apollo queries by conditionally rendering components?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, components, react-apollo

A question about general react program flow/good practices. I need to know the user's GPS coordinates, so I have a parent component for my map class which gets the users lat/lng, and then once that is received, I generate a component which has a graphQL function wrapped around it that uses the lat/lng I retrieved and finds locations available near the user. Once these lat/lng location values are retrieved, I generate a new component which passes the locations in as props so the google map can generate markers for them. is this the proper react/apollo way to handle this scenario? If not, how can I improve it?

Code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import MapContainer from './Map/GoogleMap'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  //retrieve the users GPS coordinates
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({ lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude});
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  render(){
  //kind of buggy here, on first render, this.props.lat is undefined, then after this.state.lat !== 0, it runs the graphQL query, so then this.state.lat value gets set to this.props.lat, and this.state.lat is reset to 0. Probably should be a better way to do this...
    if(!this.props.lat){
      if(this.state.lat === 0){
        return <p>Getting your location..</p>
      }
    }

    if(this.props.retrieveLocationsQuery && this.props.retrieveLocationsQuery.loading) {
      return <div>Getting the freshest spots</div>
    }
    if(this.props.retrieveLocationsQuery && this.props.retrieveLocationsQuery.error) {
      return <div>Error</div>
    }
    let renderedComponent = this.props.retrieveLocationsQuery
    ? <MapContainer lat={this.props.lat} lng={this.props.lng} locations={this.props.retrieveLocationsQuery.locations} />
    : <LocationQuery lat={this.state.lat} lng={this.state.lng} />
    return (
      <div>
        {renderedComponent}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
const RETRIEVE_LOCATIONS_QUERY = gql`
  query locations ($lat: Float!, $lng: Float!){
    locations (lat: $lat, lng: $lng){
      id
      loc {
        lat
        lng
      }
      title
      description
      times
      createdBy {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
const LocationQuery = graphql(RETRIEVE_LOCATIONS_QUERY, {name: 'retrieveLocationsQuery'})(Home)
```

Comment: you can't do `if` in render method, could be like this instead `{!this.props.lat && !this.state.lat && <p>Getting your location..</p>}`

Comment: you can, but you can not inside of the return method. example of it working in a graphQL tutorial
https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/2-queries-loading-links/

Or did you mean something about best practices?

Comment: You're right, my bad.

Comment: no worries, you're helping keep me on my toes. haha